# console.log not being called from generator function

Tags: javascript

I'm using generator functions in javascript for the first time and running in to some interesting problems.

Code:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export default function recur(quantity, units) {
  console.log('TESTING 1');

  function* recurGenerator(startDate, maxDate) {
    console.log('TESTING 2');

    if (maxDate === undefined) {
      this.throw('Argument maxDate is undefined');
    }

    let nextDate = moment(startDate).clone();
    maxDate = moment(maxDate);

    for (;;) {
      nextDate = moment(nextDate).clone().add(quantity, units);
      if (nextDate.isAfter(maxDate)) yield null;
      yield nextDate;
    }
  }

  return recurGenerator;
}
```

The "TESTING 2" console.log never gets called. It also doesn't raise an error if I don't pass maxDate to the generator function. This must be something about generator's I'm missing.

EDIT TO SHOW USAGE

```
recur(1, 'day')(moment())
```

It seems that next needs to be called to run code before the first yield?

Comment: Where's the code that uses the generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a generator function, the code before the first `yield` statement gets executed not sooner than the generator proceeds to that point:

```
let a = function * () {
  console.log(1);
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
} 

let b = a(); // no console output!
let c = b.next(); // prints 1 to the console
c // { value: 2, done: false }
```

Comment: I think this is the issue. Next needs to be called on the returned generator object to run code before the first yield?

Comment: Yes, next has to be called to proceed the execution to the next yield statement. Before that, you may think of the generator as "paused" at line zero of the function.